# How to write an array to a row in Google Sheets (via script)?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I write this array to a row?

I've tried it with `.map()`, `setValues()`,etc and none of them has worked so far.
This one write only the first element to the first column.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
.setValues([rowData])
```

and that is because you want to set multiple values (`setValues`) and you need to pass a 2D array `[[]]`.

Comment: To a beginner, this can get tricky! Thank you!